# Is there a way to query non-leaf pages value in InnoDB, just using SQL command?

Tags: mysql, innodb

InnoDB uses a B+Tree structure for its indexes.
Pages in InnoDB are referred to as being “leaf” pages or “non-leaf” pages.Leaf pages contain actual row data. Non-leaf pages contain only pointers to other non-leaf pages, or to leaf pages.
Is there a way to query primary key values in Non-leaf pages for an InnoDB table, just using SQL command.

Comment: SQL has no syntax to access internal InnoDB storage structure. In general, SQL queries by data values, not by structure.

Comment: It's not clear in your question why you need to do this. What are you really trying to do? This sounds like an XY Problem: http://xyproblem.info

Comment: Is there an InnoDB command through the MySQL client?

Comment: You still haven't described what you're trying to do. Perhaps if you start there, someone may be able to suggest a better solution that is available.